# Redirect loop, add-{type}-node redirects to add-{type}-node for non-admin users when parent type not availab.e

Tags: users, organic-groups, redirection

Users without admin permissions get a redirect loop error when they try to create a certain (organic group content) content type, when the parent (organic group) content type does not exist.

That is, instead of getting the edit form or a 403 error, they go straight to a redirect loop error. We do not have have any 403 redirect overrides, so that's not the cause. The .htaccess file is the default one provided by the Drupal installation.

Using the "display redirection page" reveals that the add node form is redirected  to the add node form in this situation. I've been unable to find any any Rule or other setting that could be causing this.

I am not using the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module (which research indicates is the most common cause of this problem). Putting the site into maintenance mode and turning off all path, url, and indexing related modules, including Pathauto and Rules, (and reverting to the default Drupal theme) doesn't solve the problem.

The problem does not occur for anyone with the "override access permissions" privilege set.

Any thoughts

1. as to what might be causing this or
2. next steps I can take trying to debug this problem?

Comment: As is so often the case, the real problem was something else entirely, and this was just an obfuscating detail. I'll update once I've untangled it all.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module that can be used to perform redirects also. So check if your sites uses this module. If so, verify if you have any "**Active**" Rules (and/or Rules Components) with a **Rules Action** that issues a redirect.

If no such Rules can be found, then it is not Rules causing your issue. If such Rules (and/or Rules Components) do exist, then temporary disable all such Rules and check if the redirect loop still happens.

If the redirect loop no longer happens, then re-enable the temporary disabled Rules again, one by one, until the problem (loop) starts again. Then disable that Rule again and use Rules debugging facilities to find out what the (customization related) problem with that rule is. For more details about debugging facilities in Rules, refer to my answer to ""[How to loop through comments using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193006/how-to-loop-through-comments-using-the-rules-module/193007#193007)".

Comment: Actually, I disabled the Rules module entirely as a test, even though there weren't any rules I thought would cause the problem; no dice. But thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Since you do have Rules and Devel, maybe a (temporary) Rules action like "Display a value" might help to further debug what the real cause for your issue is" ... (cfr my answer to the linked question for some more details on that).